# Is there a modern source control system that allows hiding contributors from each other (but not the admin)?

Tags: git, version-control

We have a project where we'd like to invite multiple different teams to work on the codebase, but not be able to see which of the other teams contributed a particular set of changes. It doesn't seem to be possible to do this with github/git, since the contributor names are part of the commit log. Is there any source control system that supports a contributor permission level that masks the origin of commits (while still letting the administrators see who contributed what)?

Comment: Why would you *want* this? :> Anyway, create anonymous accounts, lie about the commit email, or use a patch proxy, etc, .. and have fun. But to switch away from Git for this "reason" is pure nonsense.

Comment: Assume there's an external requirement that's non-negotiable. Just using anonymous accounts doesn't actually solve this problem since then the admins won't know who's who. Is there a patch proxy that anonymizes commits?

Comment: Oh cute, followed the previous link to https://help.github.com/articles/keeping-your-email-address-private/ - still doesn't help with leaking Github accounts themselves though.

Comment: Easy enough, just run a filter-branch after every inbound push. People pushing would then have to immediately fetch and then rebase anything they hadn't yet pushed, because their commits are being rewritten out from under them.  f-b keeps the originals around, see its docs for what it leaves behind.